# control Tab view in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Tab view Designed in my xamarin app application and i need to controlled it by navigation and appears specific pages, I put it by default in first page and want to navigate the second one.

this is my TabView :

```
  <Grid>
                <xct:TabView
                TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
                TabStripBackgroundColor="White"
                TabStripHeight="60"
                TabIndicatorColor="#2196f3"
                TabContentBackgroundColor="#2196f3">

                    <xct:TabViewItem
                    Icon="triangle.png"
                    Text="Patient Details"
                    TextColor="#2196f3"
                    TextColorSelected="#2196f3"
                    FontSize="12"
                        >
                        <Grid 
                        BackgroundColor="Gray">
                            <Label
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Text="TabContent1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </xct:TabViewItem>

                    <xct:TabViewItem
                    Icon="circle.png"
                    Text="Patient Follows up"
                    TextColor="#2196f3"
                    TextColorSelected="#2196f3"
                    FontSize="12">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label    
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Text="TabContent2" />
                        </Grid>
                    </xct:TabViewItem>
                </xct:TabView>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: are you asking how to programmatically switch tabs?  Your question is very unclear

Comment: not switch, but I want to navigate it into specific pages

Comment: a TabView doesn't have navigable pages, just views

Comment: ok, but when i put my view inside `<Grid 
                        BackgroundColor="Gray">` nothing appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could not navigate pages inside `TabView`. `TabView` items accepts only views. This issue has be asked before and no feature supported for now.

You could use `Shell` instead. `Shell` supports tabs for pages. And you could do the navigation to specific tab wit the routes.

For the tabs in `Shell`, you could you use `Tabbar` directly or use the tab in `FlyoutItem` to achieve the similar featrures of TabView in Shell.

Register the routes:

```
<Shell ...>
<FlyoutItem ...
            Route="animals">
    <Tab ...
         Route="domestic">
        <ShellContent ...
                      Route="cats" />
        <ShellContent ...
                      Route="dogs" />
    </Tab>
        
...
</Shell>
```

Navigate to cats page:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//animals/domestic/cats");
```

For more details, you could refer to to the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation